# Displaying a pdf file (longblob file from mysql) using view.php

Tags: php, pdf

I want to see the pdf file that is stored in a certain row of a student, I have tried to use view.php that has **header('Content-type: application/pdf');** but it doesn't seem to work. I always got this message.

[image]

**Code in my view.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

**Code of my table**

```
<td><?php echo $row["Stud_ID"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Course"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Lastname"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Firstname"]; ?></td>
    <td><a href="view.php"><?php echo $row["PSA"]; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Form137"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Picture"]; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in view.php

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($your_blob_content);?>" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></object>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\RMS\view.php on line 5

Comment: <?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($your_blob_content);?>" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></object>
?>

Comment: The same as the code in the above, i have only added the <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($your_blob_content);?>" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></object> below

Comment: Replace $your_blob_object with the content stored in your database

Comment: how? ive been thinking that the variable must be relative to the ID so that if i view that student document it is form him or her